# rake aborted! undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I'm getting this error every time I run "sudo bundle exec rake snorby:setup".

Also, I'm very new to this and can't figure out what it is that I'm doing wrong. Please let me know if more information is needed in order to adequately answer the question.

**Full trace:**

```
ciscadet@farnsworth:/var/www/snorby$ sudo bundle exec rake snorby:setup
No time_zone specified in snorby_config.yml; detected time_zone: US/Eastern
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Tasks: TOP => snorby:setup => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
ciscadet@farnsworth:/var/www/snorby$ sudo bundle exec rake snorby:setup --trace
No time_zone specified in snorby_config.yml; detected time_zone: US/Eastern
** Invoke snorby:setup (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-rails-1.2.1/lib/dm-rails/setup.rb:11:in `setup'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-rails-1.2.1/lib/dm-rails/railtie.rb:90:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `block in run_load_hooks'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/var/www/snorby/config/environment.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.12/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.12/lib/rails/application.rb:203:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:112:in `invoke_task'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `each'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:90:in `block in top_level'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:84:in `top_level'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:62:in `block in run'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:129:in `standard_exception_handling'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/application.rb:59:in `run'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/bin/rake:32:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => snorby:setup => environment
```

Comment: `snorby_config.yml` file?

Comment: whats on `/var/www/snorby/vender/cache/ruby/1.9.1/gems/dm-rails-1.2.1/lib/dm-rails/setup.rb:11`?

Answer (score 0):

**No Method**

The error is here:

> No time_zone specified in snorby_config.yml; detected time_zone:
>   US/Eastern rake aborted!

The `no method error` basically means the object you're calling `.each` on does not exist. Most people think it's the method call which is the issue, but the opposite is true - it's a lack of `object`

The way to fix this problem is to make sure your `object` is defined. Typically, you'd achieve this by defining the relevant `@instance variable`; however it seems your current issue is with `snorby_config.yml`

--

**snorby_config.yml**

According to their [`github example`](https://github.com/Snorby/snorby/blob/master/config/snorby_config.yml.example) - `snorby_config.yml`, you should have it populated in `config/snorby_config.yml`

Looking at your error log, it seems Rails is unable to invoke `snorby:setup`, thus leading to the other error you're seeing. To fix this, you will want to ensure you've set up `snorby` correctly:

```
$ rake snorby:setup
```